# Bootstrap Typography Fail 1 - No class attribute with appropriate values for uppercase and reverse not found

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, uppercase, blockquote

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="/additional_files/js/webtechnology/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/additional_files/js/webtechnology/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>THE <abbr title="North South East West">NEWS</abbr></h2>
            <p class="bg-success">This is an e-paper that collatesnational and world news</p>
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><mark>National News</mark></div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-primary">This section displays all national news and events</div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><mark>World News</mark></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">This section displays all world news and events</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <p class="text-uppercase">copyright :- the news india company</p>
            <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse text-warning">Warning:- Do Not Reproduce</blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code which I wrote. When I run this code I can the output but on evaluation, it showing error. Fail 1 - No class attribute with appropriate values for uppercase and reverse not found

Comment: The best way of posting a question is to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code using the [<>] snippet editor, rather than posting a picture of your code. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) pages can help you understand how to ask a question.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you.. Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the same problem recently and finally got what they were expecting and here's the solution to our problem:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>THE <abbr title="North South East West">NEWS</abbr></h2>
  <p class="bg-success">This is an e-paper that contains national and world news</p>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><mark>National News</mark></div>
      <div class="panel-body text-primary"><small>This section displays all national news and events</small></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><mark>World News</mark></div>
      <div class="panel-body"><small>This section displays all world news and events</small></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<blockquote>
  <p class="text-uppercase">Copyright :- The news india company</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
  <p class="text-warning">Warning:- Do Not Reproduce</p>
</blockquote>
```

We need to enclose last two paragraph tags with separate blockquote tags.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet doesn't reproduce the error you listed: *No class attribute with appropriate values for uppercase and reverse not found*, but one thing to fix is there's no closing quote mark after en:

`<html lang="en> -> <html lang="en">`

and one thing to modify is usually DOCTYPE is in uppercase (not required, but the norm):

`<!Doctype html> -> <!DOCTYPE html>`

Do your code would be like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>THE <abbr title="North South East West">NEWS</abbr></h2>
    <p class="bg-success">This is an e-paper that collatesnational and world news</p>
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><mark>National News</mark></div>
            <div class="panel-body text-primary">This section displays all national news and events</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><mark>World News</mark></div>
            <div class="panel-body">This section displays all world news and events</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="text-uppercase">copyright :- the news india company</p>
        <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse text-warning">Warning:- Do Not Reproduce</blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you're still getting the error, you can edit your question to include the exact text for the error and where it's being seen (e.g. in the browser console?). One note - you're using Bootstrap 3, but you used the Bootstrap-4 tag. If need more help, you can update your tag.

Comment: The above changes I did. Though getting the same error. The error is seen in the accenture online editor https://accenturelearning.tekstac.com/. Could you please let me know the bootstrap-4 tag which I used..

Comment: I’m not familiar with the Accenture online editor, and I don’t have access to it. One way to troubleshoot an error is to start with a new page that doesn’t have the error and then add your code, piece by piece to the new page until you get the error. That will tell you where the error is coming from. The *tag* that I was referring to is StackOverflow tags you selected for your question. You selected html, css, bootstrap-4, uppercase, and blockquote. Your code is using Bootstrap 3, not 4, so for any future questions, you should use bootstrap-3 as a tag.

Comment: I tried that way.. but didn't find why I'm getting so. By the way, bootstrap-3 tag is not available. so I selected bootstrap-4 tag..

Comment: For the older versions of Bootstrap, you can use the twitter-bootstrap tag.